# Collection of range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, collections, range

Is there a way to make this code better by using a Collection or Array ?

I want to put all this Range in some kind of dictionary for an easy use of it, can you show me a solution with an example showing me how to access data ?

```
Dim A01 As Range, A02 As Range, A03 As Range, A04 As Range, B01 As Range, B02 As Range, B03 As Range, B04 As Range, C01 As Range, C02 As Range, C03 As Range, C04 As Range, D01 As Range, D02 As Range, D03 As Range, D04 As Range, E01 As Range, E02 As Range, E03 As Range, E04 As Range, F01 As Range, F02 As Range, F03 As Range, F04 As Range

Set A01 = Range("B5:B51")
Set A02 = Range("E5:E51")
Set A03 = Range("H5:H51")
Set A04 = Range("K5:K51")

Set B01 = Range("O5:O51")
Set B02 = Range("R5:R51")
Set B03 = Range("U5:U51")
Set B04 = Range("X5:X51")

Set C01 = Range("AB5:AB51")
Set C02 = Range("AE5:AE51")
Set C03 = Range("AH5:AH51")
Set C04 = Range("AK5:AK51")

Set D01 = Range("AO5:AO51")
Set D02 = Range("AR5:AR51")
Set D03 = Range("AU5:AU51")
Set D04 = Range("AX5:AX51")

Set E01 = Range("BB5:BB51")
Set E02 = Range("BE5:BE51")
Set E03 = Range("BH5:BH51")
Set E04 = Range("BK5:BK51")

Set F01 = Range("BO5:BO51")
Set F02 = Range("BR5:BR51")
Set F03 = Range("BU5:BU51")
Set F04 = Range("BX5:BX51")

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In A01
    Debug.Print cell.Value
Next cell
```

**EDIT** : 
For example I want to access data like MyArray[A02]...

Comment: Well yes add to a dictionary or collection and then you can store the name as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a collection like this:

```
Sub NameMyRange()

    Dim oCol As New Collection
    Dim oCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")  ' <-- Change sheet name
        oCol.Add .Range("B2:B5"), "AO1"     ' <-- Set all your range like this
        oCol.Add .Range("C2:C5"), "AO2"
    End With

    ' Loop through any range like so
    For Each oCell In oCol.Item("AO2")
        MsgBox oCell.Value2
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand this

Comment: Glad it helped. Quick note: please don't use reserved words as your variable name (i.e. **`cell`**). I changed it to **`oCell`**

Answer (score 2):

One possibility using array, like this:

```
 Sub test()
    Dim arrOfRanges As Variant
    arrOfRanges = Array(Range("B5:B51"), Range("E5:E51"), Range("H5:H51"), Range("K5:K51"))
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim vv As Variant
    For Each v In arrOfRanges
        v.Interior.ColorIndex = 5 'Test: coloring ranges
        For Each vv In v
            Debug.Print vv.value ' Writing all the values of all ranges
        Next vv
    Next v
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I access to the A02 name with this kind of array ? I want something like array[A02] for example

Comment: In fairness you didn't spell that out in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use the name, you can create named ranges like this:

```
 Sub test2()
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="NameNA01", RefersTo:=Range("B5:B51")
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In [NameNA01]
        v.Interior.ColorIndex = 9 'Test: coloring ranges
    Next v
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry as I'm not exactly understand on what you expect, 
and don't quite understand on what you mean of "dictionary" for easy of use it.

But I guess maybe this is something that you want :
[image]

But it use a UserForm with one ListBox and one CommandButton.

```
Const nOffset As Variant = 13  '---> offset number from each group to next group
Public Function arr()
arr = Array(2, 5, 8, 11) '---> columns number of the first group
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Z = 0
FirstCol = arr(0)
Do
Cells(5, FirstCol).Select
If Cells(5, FirstCol).Value = "" Then Exit Do
alphabet = Chr(Asc("A") + Z)
For P = 1 To UBound(arr) + 1
ListBox1.AddItem alphabet & Format(P, "00")
Next
Z = Z + 1
FirstCol = FirstCol + nOffset
P = 0
Loop
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
x1 = Left(ListBox1.Value, 1)
x2 = Right(ListBox1.Value, 1) - 1
idx = Range(x1 & 1).Column - 1
ofst = idx * nOffset
OffCol = arr(x2) + ofst
Set Rng = Range(Cells(5, OffCol), Cells(51, OffCol))
Rng.Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

The code assumes that it has a pattern like this :
Each group will always have the same distance, 
which in this case, the next data is in the third column. 
So, the array column number of first group is : 2, 5, 8, 11

The first column of the next group will always has 3 column distance from the last column of the group before. So in this case, the offset number from each group's first column to next group's first column is 13, the nOffset.

If your data model is exactly like you put in the question,
then you don't have to change anything to the code.